# Local Storage to store ascending/descending order

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this 'sort' button in my code that sorts the prices of courses according to highest to lowest and vice versa. The button works perfectly fine, I am now trying to do local storage to preserve the order (descending or ascending) so that the order stays the same even if the page refreshes. Here is my local storage code:

```
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('order', JSON.stringify(courses));
    });
  
var orderList = localStorage.getItem('order');
  
   function getCourseOrder() {
      if (orderList) {
        return JSON.parse(orderList);
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    }

 window.onload = function() {
 generateList(getCourseOrder())
}
//generateList is to create elements and append etc
```

The problem is the order (descending/ascending) stays the same for only one refresh, then it returns to the original after the second refresh. I have created a codepen: https://codepen.io/ShawnTan15/pen/vYxebyO

Comment: instead of setting the entire sorted courses in local storage, why don't you set a "direction" flag in localStorage that gets updated/set whenever the "sort" button is clicked, then when the app loads you just read the direction flag from localStorage and sort on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through your JS code and there is only one minor mistake you have made, in onload function you also have to modify the `courses` variable, so when next (2nd) unload happens, it will take the correct sorted courses (because you are setting the local courses list to localstorage) instead of global `courses` list.

```
// Made it let
let courses = [
  {
    name: "Complete ReactJS course",
    price: "2.3",
  },
  {
    name: "Complete Angular course",
    price: "2.1",
  },
  {
    name: "Complete Mern course",
    price: "2.9",
  },
  {
    name: "Complete C++ course",
    price: "2.4",
  },
];

function generateList(courseList) {
  const ul = document.querySelector(".list-group");
  ul.innerHTML = "";
  courseList.forEach((course) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("list-group-item");
    const name = document.createTextNode(course.name);
    li.appendChild(name);
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.classList.add("float-right");
    const price = document.createTextNode("$ " + course.price);
    span.appendChild(price);
    li.appendChild(span);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
}

generateList(courses);

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-success");
let activeSortingType;
let isSortingDirty = false;
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  isSortingDirty = true;
  if (activeSortingType === "asc") {
    activeSortingType = "desc";
    courses.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
  } else if (activeSortingType === "desc") {
    activeSortingType = "asc";
    courses.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
  } else if (activeSortingType === null) {
    activeSortingType = "asc";
    courses.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
  }
  generateList(courses);
});

////////Local Storage////////
/////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
  localStorage.setItem("order", JSON.stringify(courses));
  if (activeSortingType !== null && isSortingDirty) {
    const currentSortingType = localStorage.setItem(
      "activeSortingType",
      activeSortingType
    );
  }
});

const orderList = localStorage.getItem("order");

function getCourseOrder() {
  if (orderList) {
    // Updating the courses list here in onload
    courses = JSON.parse(orderList);
    return courses;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  const courseList = getCourseOrder();
  activeSortingType = localStorage.getItem("activeSortingType");
  if (courseList.length) {
    generateList(courseList);
  }
};
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works well. However, one small problem, when the list is in ascending order and the page refreshes,  I have to press sort button twice for it to sort to descending order. I think it is because of btn's eventlistener function, where the first click always sort the list in ascending order. Any way to solve this? Thank you so much anyway.

Comment: The problem still persists after the edit. Should I just go with your other solution which starts with ascending order instead of the original order? Very sorry that I keep bothering you

Comment: Have updated the JS code, let me know if this works or not

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you don't save all the courses into local storage, but instead just save the order:

```js
let courses = [
  {
    name: "Complete ReactJS course",
    price: "2.3"
  },
  {
    name: "Complete Angular course",
    price: "2.1"
  },
  {
    name: "Complete Mern course",
    price: "2.9"
  },
  {
    name: "Complete C++ course",
    price: "2.4"
  }
];

function generateList() {
  const ul = document.querySelector(".list-group");
  ul.innerHTML = "";

  courses.forEach((course) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("list-group-item");
    const name = document.createTextNode(course.name);
    li.appendChild(name);
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.classList.add("float-right");
    const price = document.createTextNode("$ " + course.price);
    span.appendChild(price);
    li.appendChild(span);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
}

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-success");

let desc = localStorage.getItem("order") == "descending";

function sortCourses() {
  courses.sort((a, b) => desc ? b.price - a.price : a.price - b.price);
}

sortCourses();

btn.onclick = () => {
  desc = !desc;

  sortCourses();

  generateList();
}

//////// Local Storage ////////
///////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
  localStorage.setItem("order", desc ? "descending" : "ascending");
});

window.onload = () => generateList();
```

Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/mrcodingb/pen/BaWwMVd)